# passing the QAction's QString text as an argument

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QAction` which when clicked emits a `triggered` signal which calls the slot method `RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude`

```
connect(ui.actionNouvelle_tude, &QAction::triggered, this, &RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude);
```

It is possible for `void RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude()` to take a `QString` parameter if I change its definition. But how can i have `QAction::triggered` give its text `QString` parameter to `void RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude()` ?
That is, if my `QAction` is named "etude 1", is there anyway that `RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude(QString)` gets called as  `RegroupEtudes::OnNouvelleEtude("etude 1")` ?

Comment: You don't need to pass an argument to the slot. Please refer to `QObject::sender()` function to get the pointer of the signal sender (`QAction` in your case). Once you get it, you can obtain the text too.

Comment: @vahancho thanks, i didn't know about this, it works perfectly. This is typically when I don't know if I should delete my stack Overflow question or make an answer with `QObject::sender()`

Comment: Note that this approach increases coupling: your callback now needs to know which widget activated it and how to get a text out of it. Although this is not so bad if the source object is a `QAction` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Qt5, you can use a lambda expression and the new `connect` synthax to pass an extra parameter to your slot:

```
QAction *actionNouvelle_tude = new QAction(tr("Nouvelle étude..."), this);
    connect(actionNouvelle_tude, &QAction::triggered, this, [openAct, this]() {
                              this->OnNouvelleEtude(openAct->text());
});
```

It will call `OnNouvelleEtude` with the text of your action as parameter

Comment: This, like vahancho's comment, solves the problem. However this answer not only solves the problem but also answers the question (ie how to pass an argument through `connect` while using `QAction::triggered`) therefore I chose it. Thanks !